# I need to search a string for a word, how do i make it case insensitive?

Tags: python, string, task

This is my code so far

```
sentence= input("Enter a sentence")
keyword= input("Input a keyword from the sentence")
keyword.upper() == keyword.lower()
words = sentence.split(' ')
for (i, subword) in enumerate(words)  
    if (subword == keyword)  
        print(i+1)
if (keyword not in sentence)  
    print("Sorry, that word wasnt found in the sentence")
```

The following does not work

```
keyword.upper() == keyword.lower()
```

what could i add to my code?

Comment: What is "`keyword.upper() == keyword.lower()`" supposed to accomplish?

Comment: offcourse keyword.upper() == keyword.lower() will give always False

Comment: try to print it with "print keyword.upper() == keyword.lower()" and after that i think you should convert all to lower and then compare the keyword with sentence

Comment: @Harish There's no evidence that this is Python 2 code, and Python 3 has no `raw_input`.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani not if `keyword` is blank, or contains only numbers, or punctuation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually check whether a substring is part of another string using the `in` keyword:

```
sentence = input("Sentence: ")
keyword = input("Keyword: ")

if keyword in sentence:
    print("Found it!")
else:
    print("It's not there...")
```

To become case insensitive, you have to compare a lowercase version of the sentence with a lowercase version of the keyword (or both uppercase, no difference):

```
if keyword.lower() in sentence.lower():
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see your logic in trying to set upper() and lower() to the same values but it doesn't quite work like that.

Where you are comparing the subword and keyword you need to call either .upper() or .lower() on both of the so that they will both always be lowercase or both be uppercase.

Comment: If you demonstated what `.lower()` and `.upper()` do then this would be the best answer in showing where the OP's attempt went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code like this:

```
sentence= input("Enter a sentence")
keyword = input("Input a keyword from the sentence").lower()
Found   = False
words   = sentence.split(' ')
for (i, subword) in enumerate(words)  
    if (subword.lower() == keyword)  
        print('keyword found at position', i+1)
        Found = True
if not found:  
    print("Sorry, that word wasn't found in the sentence")
```